# Binding values in Repeater using 'container.dataitem'

Tags: asp.net, listbox, repeater, listboxitem, listbox-control

**lstGroup1** is a listbox ID and **arraylist1** is a ArrayList.Below is the code for binding value to the repeater from an arraylist.Its working properly.

```
lstGroup1.Items.Add(((ListItem)arraylist1[i]));
```

but i also need to bind the arraylist value into a repeater.Is that posible.?Can anyone please help..???

Repeater Aspx:

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="RptrSummary" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RptrSummary_ItemDataBound" >
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
      <tr>
       <td>
       <asp:Label ID="lblSumName" runat="server" Text= '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SUMMARY_NAME") %>'></asp:Label>

       </td>
 </table>
     </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

in this Repeater if i simply put Container.DataItem then the Arraylist is getting Binded, but its not working in the above Eval.Container.

Comment: @JackPettinger:its working when i put as " Container.DataItem"

Answer (score 0):

To bind your arraylist to the repeater simply do this:

```
MyRepeater.DataSource = myArrayList;
MyRepeater.DataBind();
```

Comment: :Thanks for the reply.If i put like " Container.DataItem " alone then the value is getting bind to the repeater.If i did in the above method its not working properly.